# Open file to read Numbers and add it to the link list

Tags: java, file-io

Working with file and linked list. The code i have reads double numbers from the file and supposed to add it to "link list". When it displays numbers it asks user to enter a double number. In the output it does not add typed number into the linked list. Not sure how to add those numbers into the link list, so i can manipulate it such as (add/delete).

```
public class LinkList
{
  public static void main(String [] args) 
  {
    linkedListNumbers numbers= new linkedListNumbers();
    numbers.newLinkList();   
    numbers.addElementToList();
  }
}

class NumNode 
{
  private double num;
  private NumNode next;

  public NumNode()
  { 
    next = null;
  }

  public NumNode(double num)
  {
    this.num = num;
    next = null;
  }

  public void setNum(double num)
  {
    this.num = num;
  }

  public double getNum()
  {
    return num;
  }

  public void setNext(NumNode next)
  {
    this.next = next;
  }

  public NumNode getNext()
  {
    return next;
  }

  public String toString()
  {
    String str = "" + num;
    return str;
  }
}

class linkedListNumbers
{
  private NumNode head;
  private int count;
  NumNode aNode = new NumNode();

  public void newLinkList()
  {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    Scanner fileScan;
    boolean validName = false;
    double num = 0.0;
    boolean validNumber = false;

    NumNode current = null;
    NumNode previous = null;

    do
    {
      System.out.print("Enter file name: ");
      String str = scan.nextLine();
      try 
      {
        fileScan = new Scanner(new File(str));
        validName = true;

        double count = 0;
        while(fileScan.hasNextLine())
        {
          try
          {
            str = fileScan.nextLine();
            num = Double.parseDouble(str);
            validNumber = true;
            count++;
            System.out.print(String.format("\t%6.2f", num));
          }
          catch (NumberFormatException nfe) 
          {
            //System.out.println("is not a Double number");
          }   
        }

        System.out.println("\nNumber of nodes = " + count);
        System.out.println(aNode);
      }
      catch (FileNotFoundException fnfe)
      {
        System.out.println("Invalid File name: enter again");
      }
    } while(!validName);
  }

  public void printList()
  {
    NumNode current = head;
    int reading = 0;
    while(current!= null)
    {
      System.out.printf("\t%6.2f", ++reading, current.toString());
    }
  }

  public void addElementToList()
  {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    boolean validN = false;
    double num = 0.0;
    NumNode current = null;
    NumNode previous = null;
    double numToAdd = 0.0;

    double count =0;
    do
    {
      System.out.println("Enter double number");
      String str = scan.nextLine();

      try
      {
        num = Double.parseDouble(str);
        aNode.setNext(head);
        head = aNode;
        count++;
      }
      catch (NumberFormatException nfe) 
      {
        System.out.println("is not a Double number");
      }   
    } while(!validN && count<1);

    System.out.println(aNode.toString());
  }

}
```

Comment: What is the code for NumNode?  The solution to your problem depends on that...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, some general advice:

1. As Code-Guru said, your LinkedListNumbers class should just control
   the data structure--don't mess with file I/O here.
2. Start small, and work up.  Design/write the code to add items to the LinkedList **before** you write the code to handle file I/O.  Test incrementally with small datasets.  It will save you much headache later; I promise.  `:)`

In general, a LinkedList has a `head` node, which is stored in a variable at the main program level.  `head` stores a reference to the first node in the LinkedList.

Another node, called `tail` is also stored; `tail` stores a reference to the most recently added node in the LinkedList.

Each node has two properties:

1. The child node, which in your implementation, is called `next`
2. The value of the node, which in your implementation, is called `num`.

To add an item to a LinkedList, the process is:

1. Create a temporary node with the new value.  (I will call this node `tempNode`.)
2. Set the current `tail`'s child to the `tempNode`.
3. Update the `tail` node to point to the (new) last node in the LinkedList--this new last node happens to be `tempNode`.

So, let's create a subroutine called `add(double num)` that adds a value to the end of the LinkedList. (I'm writing in semi-pseudocode--you'll have to handle the fine-tuned Java.)

```
add(double num) {
  //Step 1 from above
  NumNode tempNode = new NumNode(num)

  //Step 2
  tail.child = tempNode

  //Step 3
  tail = tempNode
}
```

Now, in pseudocode, a program to fill the linked list:

```
//These should be declared globally so the add method can access them...
NumNode head
NumNode tail

//The first node is different--here you set the head.
head = new NumNode(firstReadValue)
tail = head

//Now loop through
while (There remains lines to read) {
  add(nextReadValue)
}
```

Let me know if this needs more explaination.

Comment: It's gonna take time to modify stuff.

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't answer your question; I just have some unsolicited advice about the design: the linkedListNumbers class should only control the data structure and not rely an any I/O operations. I suggest that you start by modifying `addElementToList()` to take a parameter which is the element to add to the list. This method should only be concerned with that specific task: adding an element to your linked list. All of the I/O logic should be in a separate method somewhere.  Similarly, the `newLinkedList()` method should not contain any I/O logic.